# Error ExtJS 3.4 in Firefox 30.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs

today, firefox has been updated to new version 30.0. But I have seen that many ExtJS 3.4.0 based webclient dosen't work properly now. Somebody has any ideas?

Comment: what errors are you seeing? I doubt anyone will respond to your question unless you provide more useful information

Comment: error is coming from `core/DomQuery.js:440`, ++batch is undefined.

Comment: Same for me, looking for a solution now... Looks to be some kind of scoping issue. Not having Firebug or Dev console open helps, and if I open it after the page is loaded, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be due to a known bug with FF30, read the following [bug tracker](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=998908), apparently something to do with lazy eval optimisation. Scheduled to be fixed in FF31. [Upgrading to 31](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/all/) has fixed the issue for me.

Alternatively, if you do not wish to run alpha/beta FF, not having either Dev console or Firebug while loading the page also works, just more cumbersome.

Comment: I have also issues with Extjx 3.4 and Firefox 30 AND 31:  

`TypeError: this[name] is null          ext-all-debug.js:17665
TypeError: this.grid is undefined      ext-all-debug.js:51852`  

Any idea what can it be? It used to work just fine in Firefox 29-